# OnActivityResult doesn't receive data

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, google-voice

I started in my app this activity

```
var RecordIntent= new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
StartActivityForResult(RecordIntent, (int)ResultActivityCodes.SpeechResult);
```

and i have StopRecord function

```
    void StopRecord()
     {
            SetResult(Result.Ok,RecordIntent); 
            FinishActivity((int)ResultActivityCodes.SpeechResult);
     }
```

after execute `StopRecord()` function called `OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)`

why data has been null in OnActivityResult?

how to stop correctly my Activity that variable "data"  was not null

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [setResult(int, intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method in started activity before it will be destroyed. The second parameter is a data parameter of `onActivityResult()` method.

Comment: update: nope it is not work, 
for start activity i use   
StartActivityForResult(RecordIntent, (int)ResultActivityCodes.SpeechResult);



and for stop
  SetResult(Result.Ok,RecordIntent);               FinishActivity((int)ResultActivityCodes.SpeechResult);


my data is null again!